# Completely remove Stack from Windows 10

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I am running Windows 10, VSCode, and have the Haskell Extension Pack installed.

I also have Stack installed, and would like to temporarily uninstall it to make sure I can document and explain use of Stack with Haskell in VSCode on Windows 10.

stack's command help states that the `stack uninstall` command is deprecated.

Q1: Do I even need to do this?  Is stack automatically installed with the VSCode Haskell Extension Pack? My investigation does not indicate this.

Q2. To uninstall stack (JUST TEMPORARILY! I LIKE IT!) how is this done?  Is there a new command?  Do I need to use some other install manager?  Do I simply delete an executable and helper files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I recall, on Windows, *Stack* is a program you install. I haven't tried to uninstall it, but it appears in *Apps & features* with an *Uninstall* button:

[image: Apps & features screen shot]

Have you tried clicking that button?

FWIW, the [official Stack documentation also has a sentence about uninstalling](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/v1.9.1/README/#how-to-uninstall):

> Removing `~/.stack` and `/usr/local/bin/stack` should be sufficient. You may want to delete `.stack-work` folders in any Haskell projects that you have built.

Comment: I think that does *most* of it - to be sure I'd get all the directories with `stack path` (before uninstall) and then nuke those that *survived* the uninstall - on *nix based systems it's really just the `~/.stack` folder (default install) and I think Windows is similar

Comment: Uninstalling won't remove `C:\sr` folder which acches GHC or libs or something. Also there is no `.stack` folder in your home directory. You'll also need to manually remove `%AppData%\Roaming\stack`

Answer (score 2):

To remove stack you will need to manually delete the following:

1. `C:\sr`
2. `%AppData%\Roaming\stack`

Just running uninstall won't remove those folders from your system.